# Grothendieck topology on pre/sheaves

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Given a Grothendieck topology $T$, say subcanonical, on a category $C$, we are able to talk about sheaves in $(C, T)$. Since pre/sheaves can be viewed as generalized objects of $C$ (via Yoneda functor), one natural question arises, is $Shv(C, T)$ or $Psh(C)$ a site extending the site $(C, T)$? If it is, then we take pre/sheaves on that new site, can we get more pre/sheaves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Every topos has the so-called **canonical topology**, in which a sieve is covering if and only if it is generated by a small jointly epimorphic family. (In the Grothendieck topos case, this is the same as being jointly epimorphic, because the small-generation condition is automatic.) Moreover, the category of sheaves in the canonical topology of a Grothendieck topos is equivalent to the original topos, so there are no new sheaves. See Proposition 2.2.7 in [Johnstone, *Sketches of an elephant*, Part C].

That said, it is not legitimate to form presheaves on a large site: for one thing, the resulting category is not a topos.

Comment: I saw the following way to extend the covering, although it doesn't spell out as a topology, on the presheaves. Declare a family $\{F_i\to F\}$ of presheaves as a cover if for every representable $T$ and $T\to F$ the pullback $T\times_F F_i$ is representable and  $\{T\times_F F_i\to T\}$ is a cover. I didn't think this is the same as the canonical topology you described. Maybe there is some relation?

Comment: That defines, at best, a _pretopology_. However the sieve generated by any such family is a covering sieve in the canonical topology.

Comment: Yes, I always work with pretopology.

Comment: So if $(\mathcal C,\mathcal T)$ is a subcanonical site, is the restriction of the canonical topology on $Shv(\mathcal C,\mathcal T)$ to the subcategory of representable sheaves equivalent to the original topology $\mathcal T$ on $\mathcal C$?

Comment: That is correct.